# Procedure to choose voters for State Legislative Council

Tags: constitution, political-system, india

Below is the election procedure for Legislative council.  Please read the categories of people voting listed below. Among them, how to choose the voters under section (2) and (3)?  Because there are lot of  teachers and graduates in the state. How will they choose the (1/12)th teachers and graduates ? Please explain to me. Thanks.

**The Legislative Council (Vidhan Parishad)**

Article 171 of the constitution of India defines the composition of the councils. The strength of any council shall not exceed 1/3
rd
 of the strength of the state assembly. But for smaller states, the minimum strength of the council can be forty (40). The members of the Legislative Councils comprise of people elected through five different constituencies.

( 1 )  One third (1/3rd) of the members are elected by representatives of the Local Authorities (like Municipalities, Zilla Parishads, Block Parishads etc)

(2)  One third (1/3rd) of the members are elected by members of the Legislative Assembly (the same person can’t be a member of both the houses)

(3)One-twelfth (1/12th) of the members are elected by the Graduates in the state

(4)One-twelfth (1/12th) of the members are elected by the Teachers in the state

(5)  The remaining members are nominated by the Governor. Those nominated by the Governor should have special knowledge or practical experience in Literature, science, art, co-operative movement and social service.

Answer (score 1):

The Wire described this in [an article](https://thewire.in/97508/teachers-graduates-constituencies-election/) in January.

Graduates are only able to vote if they have a university degree from an Indian university completed three-years or more before the election date. They must be an Indian citizen and resident of the area they wish to vote in.

Teachers are only able to vote if they have been a full-time teacher for at least three of the previous six years before the election date. They also must be an Indian citizen and resident of the area they wish to vote in.

To vote in these special constituencies, teachers and graduates must complete and submit a special form to the Indian government. Voter turnout is low among these groups; the article claims it is because the extra administrative work is cumbersome.

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered appropiated for SE, since at any moment the article linked may be deleted or moved. Please consider modifying your answer so it contains the info needed to solve the original question (while keeping the link to provide for sources and additional info for those who desire it).